# Seeking spatial data for very specific administrative boundaries in Ontario

Tags: shapefile, data, administrative-boundaries, canada

I was wondering if anyone might know where I can download the rectangular administrative boundaries shown in the image below.  I have highlighted one of them in red.  On the image, you can see that the naming convention consists of some sort of numeric administrative identifier, as well as a name for each area (which seems to correlate roughly to the nearest city or town of any significance).

I require the spatial file in order to provide a quote for a large project and I haven't been able to find anything.  The only information the client has is in paper format.  The title on the overview map shown below is **Provincial Series and Crown Land Use Atlas Index - 1:100,000**.  I have searched the Provincial data available from LIO, the Federal data available at GeoGratis, and I've tried numerous Google searches with no luck.

I'd like to avoid digitizing if possible.  Here's the image:

[image]

Comment: These look like the names and sheet codes of map sheets rather than administrative boundaries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks to me like a one degree wide and half degree high sheet layout of topographic maps similar to NTS.

[image]

Created with QGIS using vector raster. The numbering looks like a combination of West and North coordinates in 1/10 degrees.

This map contains an overview of 1:100,000 maps with the same numbering scheme:

http://www.mnr.gov.on.ca/stdprodconsume/groups/lr/@mnr/@water/documents/document/285331.pdf

---

**EDIT**

As a workaround, you can download the 50k NTS index from ftp://ftp2.cits.rncan.gc.ca/pub/canvec/province_gml/on/canvec_gml_ON_LI.zip The 100k index is just a concatenation of 4 adjacent 50k tiles. I added that to my QGIS map, and created the numbering from the XMIN and YMIN values of my polygons:

[image]

I found maps using the scale and sheet layout, but numbered according to the NTS here:

http://www.geologyontario.mndmf.gov.on.ca/gosportal/GeologyOntarioFAST/pubs/M5/m5_index.html

http://www.geologyontario.mndmf.gov.on.ca/gosportal/GeologyOntarioFAST/pubs/NOEGTS/noegts_index.html

Looking for NOEGTS, I came across this site:

http://www.mndm.gov.on.ca/en/mines-and-minerals/applications/ogsearth/geology-terrain-noegts

The grid you see should be the one you want. If you have Google Earth, you can play with the available kml file, or download the whole dataset.

I think what you are initially after is http://search.library.utoronto.ca/details?852485 but I doubt these are available online.

Comment: @ Andre - You are correct (+1).  That is the same numbering scheme (at the link).  It's exactly what I'm after!!  Any idea where I can get the data?  If not, I'll start by calling the The Provincial Geomatics Service Centre (the producer of the map) when Government offices open this morning .  Thanks.  How did you find this?  I googled everyting I could think of and called MNR!!

Comment: I g**gled for `820480 Timmins`, The fifth in the list ;-)

Comment: @ Andre - You are absolutely correct about the naming convention of the numbers (and the data being derived from NTS).  I was hoping to download the spatial data rather than creating it manually, but I'm going to select your answer as the correct one.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try the [LIO Metadata portal](https://www.appliometadata.lrc.gov.on.ca/geonetwork/srv/en/main.home).

Search for Crown Land Use Atlas and you'll find a couple of items that may be what you're looking for.

Comment: It looks like it could be the UTM 100KM grid.

Comment: No, the 100km grid would be squares. Crown Land Use Atlas used to be published on 100k pdf maps with the right numbering, but they changed to a web map service some time ago.